# Getting returned value from method to use in for loop

Tags: java, arrays, methods, parameter-passing

It's basic, but i cant find an answer... I am calling method Kmeans(centers, dataset, k) with 3 parameters in my Main class. The method returns centers. How can I use this return of centers in another class for loop?

From Main class calling method with...

```
concurrentKmeans(centers, dataset, k);
```

Method...

```
public static List<TockaXY> kmeans(List<TockaXY> centers, List<TockaXY> dataset, int k) {
      boolean converged;
      do {
          List<TockaXY> noviCentri = noviCentri(dataset, centers);
          double dist = dobiRazdaljoCenters(centers, noviCentri);
          centers = noviCentri;
          converged = dist == 0;
      } while (!converged);
      return centers;
  }
```

Trying to use it here in for loop to iterate the `List<TockaXY>`  ...

```
public class WebviewLoadListner implements ChangeListener<State>{

    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends State> observable, State from, State to) {
        if (to == State.SUCCEEDED)
        {
            SampleController.engine.executeScript("jumpTo("+46.641389+","+49.756667+","+10+")");
            for(int i =0; i<Main.kmeans(centers, dataset, k); i++){

            }

        }     
    }

}
```

Comment: your for loop syntax isn't correct. Try to this: for(TockaXY tock : Main.kmeans(centers, dataset, k)) {}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The better way is to call the method and set it to a local variable and then use it in the for loop. It is not ideal to use the function call inside the for loop condition, since each time it is evaluated and the same function will be called for each loop iteration, which will impact the performance.

```
SampleController.engine.executeScript("jumpTo("+46.641389+","+49.756667+","+10+")");

List<TockaXY> list = Main.kmeans(centers, dataset, k);
for(int i =0; i< list.size(); i++){
    //Use list.get(i) for each individual element in the list
}
```

or

```
List<TockaXY> list = Main.kmeans(centers, dataset, k);
for(TockaXY toc : list) {
    //toc will give individual element in the list
}
```

With JDK 8, we can use streams to access elements

```
List<TockaXY> list = Main.kmeans(centers, dataset, k);
list.stream().forEach(toc -> {
   //Your operation with toc
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your for loop you are comparing two different types `int` and `List<TockaXY>`. I think you mean to use the List's `size()`.

`i<Main.kmeans(centers, dataset, k).size();` instead of `i<Main.kmeans(centers, dataset, k);`